# Java Serialized Form?

Tags: java, serializable

Часто получаю warning, что какой-то класс не декларирует java Serialized Form, или что-то вроде.

Что сие означает?

Comment: Почитайте про сериализацию.

Comment: @smackmychi, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы.

Comment: @Expert данного ответа достаточно для того, чтобы человек имел себе представление о том, что нужно искать. В итоге по двум запросам он может найти и что такое сериализация, и как ее механизм устроен в Java.

Comment: @smackmychi, Как мне кажется, заголовок вопроса говорит о том, что автор понимает, что именно искать в поисковике, а если и нет, то хочет получить базовые знания, на которые можно будет опираться в будущем при решении проблемы. Возвращаясь к [ответу с Меты](http://meta.hashcode.ru/questions/2551#2553), оставленный вами комментарий никак не поможет пользователю и может вызвать не желание разобраться в вопросе, а негатив к тематике. Основываясь на данной логике, подобные комментарии будут удаляться. Пожалуйста, публикуйте что-то более информативное, чем отсылка в поисковик.

Comment: @Expert не соглашусь. Если бы автор хотя бы знал в общем, что такое сериализация, то на данный вопрос он нашел бы ответ самостоятельно. Объяснять по сериализации нечего - автор не сказал, что что-то именно ему непонятно. Что-то искать за человека смысла тоже не имеет - он всего лишь не знает слово и даже не хочет его поискать, тогда как вся информация лежит в открытом доступе. Исходя из этого, я решил просто дать направление. Большую работу проделывать за человека здесь не приветствуется. Тогда давайте понимать, что работа бывает разная, а не только задачки решать.

Answer (score 1):

implements Serializable - какой-то класс, который вы хотите передать с вашей формы, не имплементирует интерфейс Serializable, просто добавь воды (в данном случае implements Serializable) к своему классу.